# Celery - Completes task but never returns result

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery

I've just installed Celery and am trying to follow the tutorial:

I have a file called tasks.py with the following code:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I installed RabitMQ (I did no configuring with it since the tutorial didn't mention anything of that sort).

I run the celery worker server as follows:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

It seems to start up normally (here is the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUsap.png)

Then I run a script with the following:

```
from tasks import add
from time import sleep

result = add.delay(2,2)

while not result.ready():
    sleep(10)
```

When I check `result.ready()` I always get False (so the while loop above runs forever). On the Celery logs, however, everything looks fine:

```
[2014-10-30 00:58:46,673: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.add[2bc4ceba-1319-49ce-962d-1ed0a424a2ce]
[2014-10-30 00:58:46,674: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.add[2bc4ceba-1319-49ce-962d-1ed0a424a2ce] succeeded in 0.000999927520752s: 4
```

So the task was recived and succeeds. Yet, `result.ready()` is still False. Any insight as to why this might be? I am on Windows 7, and am using RabbitMQ. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where in your code do you run result.readh() check? You didn't include that part. It may also be worth trying result = add.delay(2,2).get(5), and see whether you will get results that way.

Comment: @Puciek For `result = add.delay(2,2).get(5)` I get `result = add.delay(2,2).get(5)` so I guess it's not getting anything back. If I try `result.readh()` I get `AttributeError: 'AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'readh'`

Comment: Please post the code where you check whether the data is ready, as it is this is pointless guessing.

Comment: @Puciek Apologizes, I am using PyScripter to run the code, then am manually checking result.ready(); I will modify the code so it is self-contained.

Comment: @Puciek `For result = add.delay(2,2).get(5)` I get `TimeoutError: The operation timed out.` (There was a typo in the earlier post)

Answer (score 5):

Should solve your problem

```
ignore_result=False
```

Comment: Where should you write that? Could you give more context please?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've set up a clear VM with fresh celery install, set the following files:

tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

And runme.py

```
from tasks import add
import time

result = add.delay(1,2)
while not result.ready():
  time.sleep(1)

print(result.get())
```

Then I set up celery with:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

And subsequently I run the runme.py which gives expected result:

```
[puciek@somewhere tmp]# python3.3 runme.py
3
```

So clearly the issue is within your setup, most likely somewhere in rabbit-mq installation, so I recommend reinstalling it with latest stable version from sources, which is what I am using, and as you can see - it works just fine.

Update:

Actually, your issue may be as trivial as imaginable - are you sure that you are using same version for celery run, and running your consumer? I just managed to reproduce it, where I've ran celery on Python3.3, and subsequently ran the runme.py with version 2.7. Result was as you've described.

Comment: @Puicek thanks for the very insightful post; I only have python2.7 installed, piped the latest version of celery, and installed the version 3.4.1 of rabbitMQ for windows. What is your VM set up, I would like to try it as well and see if that works for me?

Comment: Also tried re-installing it (no improvement). If yout VM is linux, I think this might be an windows-specific issue

Comment: @kyphos it is indeed a linux (gentoo to be specific, but I wouldn't recommend it for a newbie), give it a try and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Celery needs to have the result backend enabled. See

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-result-backend

See also http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#calling-the-task.

Comment: he set that in app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

Comment: @silviud I have the following line in tasks.py `app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')`; I thought that took care of the enabling the backend?

Comment: the setup for result backend is wrong - the prove is that you get a timeout when doing a get - you can reset your broker 'rabbitmqctl stop_app ; rabbitmqctl reset ; rabbitmqctl start_app'. You can ping your worker like this 'celery inspect ping' also you should see an exchange called celeryresults when doing 'rabbitmqctl list_exchanges' - to see if a task is still active you can use 'celery inspect active' - sorry i didn't explained better